# U Subbing Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have found something to work almost every time when taking derivatives, it is essentially just another application of the chain rule. For example when evaluating $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1} x$ making the substitution $x=\sin \theta \rightarrow dx=\cos \theta d\theta$ we can rewrite it our problem as $\frac{1}{\cos \theta} \frac{d}{d\theta}\theta$ Taking the derivative we are left with just $\frac{1}{\cos \theta}.$ Knowing that this needs to be rewritten in terms of x we get $\frac{1}{\cos (\sin^{-1} x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {1-x^2}},$ the desired answer.

Up until I came across $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1} (\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$ I thought this method would work every time. Me trying to be lazy and not do work somewhat recognized the $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ as $x=\tan (\frac{t}{2}) \implies \frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\sin t$ Using the same process as before I got the answer as $\frac{2}{1+x^2}$ however the answer was actually negative that. Can someone tell me why my method didn't work and/or other cases where this "u substitution" might not work?

Answer (score 1):

$$t:=\sin^{-1} F,\ F:=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

So $\sin\ t=F$ and $$ \cos\ t=\sqrt{1-F^2}\ {\rm or}\
-\sqrt{1-F^2}$$

Hence $\cos\ tt'=F'$ That is
$$ t'=\frac{1}{\cos\ t} F'= \frac{ F'}{\sqrt{1-F^2}} \ {\rm or}\ \frac{
-F'}{\sqrt{1-F^2}}$$